# jsonify tabs in python for an API request

Tags: python, api

I there, I got a tab from mysql like this:
`{'jean': 22, 'pierre': 26, 'john': 21, 'charles': 23, 'test': 25, 'test2': 45}` called users

And I want to Jsonify it like this:

```
[{
  "name": "jean"
  "age": 22
}
{
  "name": "pierre"
  "age" : 26
}
...
```

And I'm not able to do it. Could you help me please ?

```
@app.route("/users", methods = ['GET'])
def getUsers():
    return jsonify({'users' : users}]
```

Comment: Your call to `jsonify` has a typo: the ending character shoudld be `)` and not `]`

Answer (score 0):

It will look like this:

```
d = {'jean': 22, 'pierre': 26, 'john': 21, 'charles': 23, 'test': 25, 'test2': 45}
res = []
for k, v in d.items():
  res.append({"name": k, "age": v})

print(res)
```